# Multithreaded EJB client

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, websphere, ejb

I would like to parallelize multiple ejb calls from a java client and maintain a single transaction. the ejb is exposed on an websphere application server, and the client is a simple spring boot war deployed on the same was.
I'm able to maintain the transaction in an sequitial flow now i would like to parallelize this flow of calls.
Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere application server does not support a single transaction running concurrently on multiple threads.  This is actively enforced; any attempt to parallelize your flow with a single transaction would result in an error.

If any of the EJB calls could run in a separate transaction, then you could parallelize their calls by marking the method with the `@Asynchronous` annotation (`javax.ejb.Asynchronous`).  The return type would be `Future`, and the client could then wait for the EJB method(s) to complete if so desired.